# How to return JSON key values if they exist in a list?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to extract JSON key values if they exist in a list. I'm using Python but I keep getting no results. Is there something obvious here that I'm missing? Dummy JSON data, .js, and current Python code below for reference. Thanks!

```
{"int":1,"string":"Some string for int 1","date":"1969-1-1","metadata":"String metadata for int 1"}  
{"int":2,"string":"Some string for int 2","date":"1969-1-2","metadata":"String metadata for int 2"}  
{"int":3,"string":"Some string for int 3","date":"1969-2-1","metadata":"String metadata for int 3"}  
{"int":4,"string":"Some string for int 4","date":"1970-1-1","metadata":"String metadata for int 4"}  
{"int":5,"string":"Some string for int 5","date":"1969-1-1","metadata":"String metadata for int 5"}
```

I want to extract objects from that JSON file with "int" keys that also occur in a .js file I created. The .js file simply looks like:

```
2,5
```

So with this dummy data, my desired output would be a newly written JSON containing the following:

```
{"int":2,"string":"Some string for int 2","date":"1969-1-2","metadata":"String metadata for int 2"}  
{"int":5,"string":"Some string for int 5","date":"1969-1-1","metadata":"String metadata for int 5"}
```

Here's my Python code so far:

```
import json
import re

ids = open('dummy-ids.js', 'r').read().split(',')
dataset = set(ids)

with open('dummy2.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for obj in data:
    if obj["id"] in dataset:
        print(obj)
    else:
        print(str(obj["id"]) + " not found")
```

The above code results in all Ids being not found. Let me know if anything is unclear. Thanks again!

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but it's not the IDs you want to extract from `toomanyIDs.json` but their corresponding objects, no?

Also it would be nice if you could provide us with a toy example like a few lines from each file.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a subset of what's in the `'desiredIDs.js` file and small sample of the JSON data being processed.

Comment: You might want to convert that `listof500` from a list to a `set()`. That way you can do a lookup for each `data[0]['id']` to see if it is in the set in a very fast way. Otherwise you would have to put in a nested for loop to check for a match of every value in the `listof500` for each `data[0]['id']`.

Comment: Thanks, everyone! I'll experiment with `set()` for now and will gather some dummy data. I probably won't have that until later tonight or tomorrow. Thanks again!

Comment: @LéopoldHoudin, I want to return the IDs along with some corresponding data. Will work on getting a toy example soon!

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over `data` like this:

```
for obj in data:
    if obj['id'] in listof500:
        print(obj)
```

Note that the `in` operator would be more efficient if you convert `listof500` to a set first:

```
setof500 = set(listof500)
for obj in data:
    if obj['id'] in setof500:
        print(obj)
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems like it should work, but for whatever reason, it doesn't return any results. I'm working from the dummy data that was added to the top of the question. I can't seem to get the "int":2 from the JSON to match with the 2 in my set.

Answer (score 0):

If follow your code,you should be:

```
import json
import re

listof500 = open('desiredIDs.js', 'r').read().split(',')

with open('toomanyIDs.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for d in data.values():
    if d["id"] in listof500:
        print(each)
```

But on my understanding,you seem to be finding Intersection.If it is real,then you can do so:

```
import json
import re

listof500 = open('desiredIDs.js', 'r').read().split(',')

with open('toomanyIDs.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

ins = set([d["id"] for d in data.values()]) & set(listof500)
```